# Using three in ECMA Script 6 STL Viewer class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am trying to convert a Three STL viewer demonstration into an ES6 Class which is then compiled with webpack 2 but i want it to open the file from URL rather than from an actual file input, ive managed to load the three components and most of the class is working but i think i am having problems in the scope with a few of the components, ive ran into a problem i dont seem to be able to get past when trying to use FileReader and then opening the scene and object. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined`

#### threeDimensionalModels.js

```js
// jshint esversion:6
import {
  Scene, PerspectiveCamera, WebGLRenderer, Geometry, Mesh,
  AmbientLight, DirectionalLight, MeshPhongMaterial, Vector3, Face3,
} from 'three';

var thisClass = null;
class threeDimensionalModels {
  constructor(height,width,selector){
    this.w = height;
    this.h = width;
    this.selector = selector;
    this.renderer = new WebGLRenderer();
    this.view = document.getElementById(this.selector);
    this.camera = new PerspectiveCamera(45, this.w / this.h, 1, 1000);
    this.scene = new Scene();
    this.light1 = new DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    this.light2 = new DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    this.mat = new MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x339900, specular: 0x030303 });
    this.obj = new Mesh(new Geometry(), this.mat);
    this.renderer.setSize(this.w, this.h);
    this.view.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
    this.camera.position.set(0, 0, 50);
    this.scene.add(new AmbientLight(0x666666));
    this.light1.position.set(0, 100, 100);
    this.scene.add(this.light1);
    this.light2.position.set(0, -100, -100);
    this.scene.add(this.light2);
    this.scene.add(this.obj);
  }


  static binaryVector3(view, offset) {
        var v = new Vector3();
        v.x = view.getFloat32(offset + 0, true);
        v.y = view.getFloat32(offset + 4, true);
        v.z = view.getFloat32(offset + 8, true);
        return v;
  }

  static loadBinaryStl(buffer) {
        // binary STL
        var view = new DataView(buffer);
        var size = view.getUint32(80, true);
        var geom = new Geometry();
        var offset = 84;
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            var normal = threeDimensionalModels.binaryVector3(view, offset);
            geom.vertices.push(threeDimensionalModels.binaryVector3(view, offset + 12));
            geom.vertices.push(threeDimensionalModels.binaryVector3(view, offset + 24));
            geom.vertices.push(threeDimensionalModels.binaryVector3(view, offset + 36));
            geom.faces.push(
                new Face3(i * 3, i * 3 + 1, i * 3 + 2, normal));
            offset += 4 * 3 * 4 + 2;
        }
        return geom;
    }

    static m2vec3(match) {
        var v = new Vector3();
        v.x = parseFloat(match[1]);
        v.y = parseFloat(match[2]);
        v.z = parseFloat(match[3]);
        return v;
    }

    static toLines(array) {
        var lines = [];
        var h = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] === 10) {
                var line = String.fromCharCode.apply(
                    null, array.subarray(h, i));
                lines.push(line);
                h = i + 1;
            }
        }
        lines.push(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, array.subarray(h)));
        return lines;
    }

    static loadTextStl(buffer) {
        var lines = threeDimensionalModels.toLines(new Uint8Array(buffer));
        var index = 0;
        var scan = function (regexp) {
            while (lines[index].match(/^\s*$/)) index++;
            var r = lines[index].match(regexp);
            return r;
        };
        var scanOk = function (regexp) {
            var r = scan(regexp);
            if (!r) throw new Error(
                "not text stl: " + regexp.toString() +
                "=> (line " + (index - 1) + ")" +
                "[" + lines[index-1] + "]");
            index++;
            return r;
        };

        var facetReg = /^\s*facet\s+normal\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)/;
        var vertexReg = /^\s*vertex\s+([^s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)/;
        var geom = new Geometry();
        scanOk(/^\s*solid\s(.*)/);
        while (!scan(/^\s*endsolid/)) {
            var normal = scanOk(facetReg);
            scanOk(/^\s*outer\s+loop/);
            var v1 = scanOk(vertexReg);
            var v2 = scanOk(vertexReg);
            var v3 = scanOk(vertexReg);
            scanOk(/\s*endloop/);
            scanOk(/\s*endfacet/);
            var base = geom.vertices.length;
            geom.vertices.push(threeDimensionalModels.m2vec3(v1));
            geom.vertices.push(threeDimensionalModels.m2vec3(v2));
            geom.vertices.push(threeDimensionalModels.m2vec3(v3));
            geom.faces.push(
                new Face3(base, base + 1, base + 2, threeDimensionalModels.m2vec3(normal)));
        }
        return geom;
    }

    static loadStlModel(buffer) {
        try {
            return threeDimensionalModels.loadTextStl(buffer);
        } catch (ex) {
            return threeDimensionalModels.loadBinaryStl(buffer);
        }
    }

    openStl(url) {
      var blob = null;
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("GET", url);
      xhr.responseType = "blob";//force the HTTP response, response-type header to be blob
      xhr.onload = function() {
        blob = xhr.response;
        thisClass = this;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener("load", function (ev) {
            var buffer = ev.target.result;
            var geom = threeDimensionalModels.loadStlModel(buffer);
            threeDimensionalModels.scene.remove(thisClass.obj);
            threeDimensionalModels.obj = new Mesh(geom, threeDimensionalModels.mat);
            threeDimensionalModels.scene.add(threeDimensionalModels.obj);
        }, false);
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
     };
     xhr.send();

    }

}

export default threeDimensionalModels;
```

#### HTML

```html
<div id="threedm-view"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    "use strict";
    var threedm = new threeDimensionalModels(800,800,'threedm-view');


    var loop = function loop() {
        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        threedm.obj.rotation.z += 0.05;
        threedm.renderer.clear();
        threedm.renderer.render(threedm.scene, threedm.camera);
    };
    loop();

    threedm.openStl("/app/uploads/2017/07/Stator.stl");
});   
</script>
```

Comment: You didn't port `static remove`, also start classes with uppercase to avoid this sort of confusion in the future. Also, please isolate your examples.

Comment: Im confused, probably not a good start, `threeDimensionalModels.scene.remove(thisClass.obj);` is meant to be `THREE.Scene()` which is imported into the class and then called in the constructor `this.scene = new Scene();`

Comment: Right, so `this.scene...`

Comment: if i try calling it that way somehow it doesnt end up in the scope inside the event, so i can apply it by creating a global variable and applying this to the global variable then calling the global variable in the eventListener, but i dont think that is quite right either and even that doesn't quite work for this use case. worked with another class but not this one

Comment: i might have found the problem  `thisClass = this;` is inside the XHR function, i dont think this is in that scope, yup that was it the example is now working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a bit more playing around, and looking at the problem area, i realised that i was applying this to the global variable where this in the context i wanted did not exist, i would like to find a better way of passing this into child functions inside ECMA class functions without using a global variable

### update

```js
class threeDimensionalModels {
  // .... //
    openStl(url) {
      var blob = null;
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("GET", url);
      xhr.responseType = "blob";
      thisClass = this; // Moved from inside xhr.onload
      xhr.onload = function() {
        blob = xhr.response;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener("load", function (ev) {
            var buffer = ev.target.result;
            var geom = threeDimensionalModels.loadStlModel(buffer);
            thisClass.scene.remove(thisClass.obj);
            thisClass.obj = new Mesh(geom, thisClass.mat);
            thisClass.scene.add(thisClass.obj);
        }, false);
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
     };
     xhr.send();
    }
  // ... //
}
```